# Linear layout not covering the entire screen

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I had my layout covering the entire screen. I clicked on something and suddenly the whole layout in every screen got pushed down a little and it has made all my layout looking weird when I run it.

Here is how it looks.

[image]

If you look at image, the layout is not covering the whole screen like it used to. I have my theme. I dont think I changed my theme by accident. Even if I did, it shouldnt pushed down all the layouts in other screens too.

I was playing with color values when this happened I think.

Here is how my XML looks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CheckBox" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is how the style looks like.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

I can change the colorPrimaryDark for the current white color, but before it wasn't there. 
Can anyone help?

This is just a test layout btw

Comment: What do you mean by entire screen ? Its is currently covering entire screen. The layout is correct as per xml file. Are you talking about left and right margin ?

Comment: I meant the top. It wasn't like that before. There was no white space in there before.

Comment: You can use **negative margin**
`android:layout_marginTop = "-5dp"` in checkbox

Comment: But I’ll have to do that on all my layouts. Is there a better way ? Something which caused all my layouts to shift like that ?